# Cross compiling QT

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, qt5

I am cross compiling QT using a vendor cross compiler `gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi` and get the following error during `make`.

Does anyone know what this may be related to?

It looks like some packages has been compiled with another compiler and now there are miss-matches? Am I write in this point?

How should I solve this issue?

```
/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link,/mnt/freescale/ltib_10.04_gtt/ltib/rootfs/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/qt5/lib -o ../../bin/qmlbundle .obj/main.o   -L/mnt/freescale/ltib_10.04_gtt/ltib/rootfs/usr/lib -L/home/user/Downloads/qt5/qtdeclarative/lib -lQt5Qml -L/home/user/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/lib -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lpthread 

.obj/main.o: In function `showHelp()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2e0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x408): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x438): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x470): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4a0): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4d8): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x508): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x540): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x570): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5a8): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5d8): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x610): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x640): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x678): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x6a8): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x700): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x738): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x768): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
.obj/main.o: In function `usage(QString const&, QString const&)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x834): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x868): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x8c0): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0xa78): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xaa8): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
.obj/main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ebc): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, int)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ef4): undefined reference to `std::ctype<char>::_M_widen_init() const'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../../bin/qmlbundle] Error 1
```

I don't think it matters, but if anyone is wondering I am building QT 5.2.0 for Freescale iMX51 (Cortex-A8).

This is how I am configuring QT 5.2.0 before make:

```
./configure -v -opensource -confirm-license -opengl es2 -make libs -device imx5 \
-nomake examples -nomake tests \
-skip qtsvg -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtwebkit -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtlocation -skip qtactiveqt -qt-freetype -no-openssl -no-nis -no-pch -no-dbus \
-skip qtmacextras -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialport \
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- \
-sysroot /mnt/freescale/ltib_10.04_gtt/ltib/rootfs -no-gcc-sysroot \
-prefix /opt/qt5
```

The qmake.conf for imx5 is actually downloaded and it content looks like this:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)

EGLFS_PLATFORM_HOOKS_SOURCES = $$PWD/qeglfshooks_imx5.cpp

QMAKE_INCDIR           += $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR           += $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL         += -lEGL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2  += -lGLESv2 -lEGL
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG      += -lOpenVG -lEGL

QMAKE_LFLAGS           += -Wl,-rpath-link,$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/lib

IMX5_CFLAGS             = -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -D_LINUX
IMX5_CFLAGS_RELEASE     = -O2 $$IMX5_CFLAGS
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE   += $$IMX5_CFLAGS_RELEASE
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += $$IMX5_CFLAGS_RELEASE
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG     += $$IMX5_CFLAGS
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG   += $$IMX5_CFLAGS

include(../common/linux_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
```

Comment: can u explain for which board,platform and architecture r u cross-compiling?

Comment: @vinayhunachyal, I don't think these things should matter, but see updates for answer to your questions!

Comment: It matters while configuring u need to give option like  -device < > e.g linux-rasp-pi-g++ or -xplatform linux-g++-mx5x -release which is mkspeck of your device. also share how u compiling qt?

Comment: @vinayhunachyal, you are right. please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am cross-compiling Qt 5.0.2 for x86_64, using gcc 4.8.0.  I noticed some potentially relevant differences from your build:

During configure:

- I am not specifying `-no-gcc-sysroot`.
- I specify `-device-option TOOL_DIR=$(TOOL_DIR)`, where `TOOL_DIR` is the top-level dir of the toolchain (i.e. my cross-g++ is at `$(TOOL_DIR)/bin/`).  This is used below in my qmake.conf.
- I am using the `-platform` argument (though I think this defaults to `linux-g++-64`).

In my qmake.conf:

- I specify `QMAKE_INCDIR = $${TOOL_DIR}/include $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include`
- I do not include `linux_device_post.conf`, as the contents of that file were not relevant to me, except for the call to `deviceSanityCheckCompiler`, which I added to qmake.conf.

Here is my configure command (part of a makefile):

```
    cd $(QT_DIR) && PATH=$(QT_PATH) ./configure -v \
      -prefix $(ROOT_DIR) \
      -sysroot $(ROOT_DIR) \
      -headerdir $(TOOL_DIR)/include \
      -hostprefix $(TOOL_DIR) \
      -datadir $(TOOL_DIR) \
      -examplesdir $(TOOL_DIR) \
      -testsdir $(TOOL_DIR) \
      -platform linux-g++-64 \
      -device linux-vendorname-g++ \
      -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=$(TARGET)- \
      -device-option TOOL_DIR=$(TOOL_DIR) \
      -opensource \
      -confirm-license \
      -no-accessibility \
      -no-javascript-jit \
      -no-gui \
      -no-widgets \
      -no-gif \
      -no-libpng \
      -no-libjpeg \
      -no-openssl \
      -no-xcb \
      -no-opengl \
      -no-glib \
      -no-dbus \
      -no-cups \
      -no-pkg-config \
      -optimized-qmake \
      -reduce-relocations \
      -reduce-exports \
      -release \
      -make libs \
      -no-pch
```

`ROOT_DIR` is the top-level of the root fs, and is where the Qt libraries will get installed to.

`QT_DIR` is the top-level Qt source dir (and where the Qt build occurs).

`QT_PATH` includes `$(TOOL_DIR)/bin`, to ensure it can find my cross-compiler.

Here is my qmake.conf:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)

COMPILER_FLAGS          = -mtune=core-avx-i

#modifications to gcc-base.conf
QMAKE_CFLAGS        += $$COMPILER_FLAGS
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS      += $$COMPILER_FLAGS

#QMAKE_LFLAGS        = 

QMAKE_INCDIR            = $${TOOL_DIR}/include $$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++11

# Sanity check
deviceSanityCheckCompiler()

load(qt_config)
```

Also, it looks like you are having problems linking an application built against this version of Qt, not in building Qt itself, correct?  In that case, if you are not already, you should call the qmake you build for your toolchain (it should be a host executable).  If you use cmake, then this qmake needs to be first on the path when you 'find' Qt.